# Meaning of Iwan Rheon's "Sink"

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Please explain me the meaning of the song *Sink* by Iwan Rheon (from the EP *Changing Times*).

I don’t seem to understand it fully.

Comment: What don't you understand  exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I’d say it’s about the rise and fall of Western civilisation, and the American dream.

> You look, you look
>   you look to the west.
>   Cause they say, cause they say
>   they say it's the best.
>   Well it's fading, it's fading
>   it's fading for me.
>   But I guess, but I guess
>   that's the price to be free.

He seems to use this as an analogy to his own inner desire to not 'fall' or 'sink' as the West has done?

> Oh, you try not to sink,
>   you try not to sink with me

Comment: Ha yeah that's true too... It's down to interpretation and this time I think you're maybe right, but I still like my interprtaton 

Comment: Maybe because you're narrow minded? Have you not heard people talk about western ideals or civilisation coming to an end before? No offence but I think your interpretation is insufficient given the realities of the lyrics.

Comment: I've never heard the song, but my interpretation is mine, not yours. And more sophisticated, probably giving too much credence to what is possibly a lousy song.